# Extracting and integrating data from separate lists in Python

Tags: python, list, cluster-analysis

I have this code:

```
cursor.execute( ''' SELECT id,DISTINCT tag
                     FROM userurltag ''')
tags = cursor.fetchall ()
T = [3,5,7,2,1,2,2,2,5,6,3,3,1,7,4]
```

I have 7 groups names 1,...,7 . Each row in "tags" list corresponds to a row in "T" list.the values of "T" say that for example the first row in "tags" list belongs to group 3, the second row in "tags" list belong to group 5 and so on. These are basically the clusters to which each tag belongs.
I want to extract them, in a way that I have each group/cluster in a separate for example dictionary data type. The important thing is that the number of clusters will change in each run. So I need a general code can work with various numbers of clusters for this problem.
I seriously need you help
Thanks.

Comment: Read it three times ... I really don't understand.

Comment: Provide minimal example (given `tags` list what output you'd like to see).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cluster_to_tag = defaultdict(list)
#May want to assert that length of tags and T is same
for tag,cluster in zip(tags, T):
    cluster_to_tag[cluster].append(tag)

#cluster_to_tag now maps cluster ti list of tags
```

hth